# Consistent errors when uploading an R Leflet map to RPubs

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I'm attempting to upload a large leaflet map r-file (97.5mb) from RStudio to RPubs. I keep getting the same error and I wonder if anyone has a solution/work-around. The error states:

> "Error in rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw
>   vector Calls:  ... http ->  -> grep ->
>   parse_headers -> rawToChar Execution halted"

I've constructed a large polygon choropleth shapefile detailing all of the census tracts for Pennsylvania, New Jersey, and Delaware. When I hit "publish" in the Viewer window of RStudio, I'm first directed to choose where I want to publish the file: RPubs or RStudio Connect. I have an RPubs account so I choose that option and then click "Publish" in the second RPubs option window. I then receive a buffering label followed by an error message stating:

> "Error in rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw
>   vector Calls: ... http -> -> grep -> parse_headers -> rawToChar
>   Execution halted"

Here's the code for my map:

```r
shapefile <- readOGR("filename")

shapefile <- spTransform(shapefile,"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

### Creating the leaflet map ###
bins <- c(60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95)
pal <- colorBin("YlGnBu", domain=shapefile$lifeexpectancy, bins=bins)

m <- leaflet(shapefile) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  setView(lng=-75.165222, lat=39.952583, 11) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(lifeexpectancy),
              weight=0.5,
              opacity=1,
              color="gray",
              fillOpacity=0.4,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color="white",
                                                  weight=1.5,
                                                  bringToFront = T,
                                                  opacity = 0.7),
              label=mapply(
                function(x,y) {
                  HTML(sprintf("<strong>Life Expectancy</strong><br/><em>%s years</em><br/><strong>Median Household Income</strong><br/><em>$%s</em>",
                               htmlEscape(x),htmlEscape(y)))
                },
                shaoefile$lifeexpectancy,shapefile$`Median Household Income`, SIMPLIFY = F),
              labelOptions = lapply(1:nrow(shapefile),function(x) {
                labelOptions(direction = "auto",
                             textsize = "15px")
              })) %>%
  addLegend(pal=pal,
            values=bins,
            opacity = 0.7,
            title ="Life Expectancy<br>(in years)",
            position="bottomright")
```

I've also received the following error, once:

> "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Empty
>   reply from server Calls:  ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList ->
>   tryCatchOne ->  Timing stopped at: 0.03 0.05 1.3 Execution
>   halted"

I've seen previous answers about fixing the .Rprofile code in my system's folder, which none worked for me. Any help you can offer would be great.

Comment: I just bumped into the same problem. Have you figured out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get slimmer html files, you could try to simplify geometry of  polygons.  See [this notebook](https://rpubs.com/ials2un/leaflet_thin) for more details.